# woo rest api update status Invalid parameter(s): status [rest_invalid_param]

Tags: php, post, woocommerce-rest-api

It was working fine, suddenly it stopped and I got  Invalid parameter(s): status [rest_invalid_param], its been like 2 days searching for answers

the error is thrown directly on the php page, where I have debug enabled
this my html where from a select, I select the status I want to update

```
  <form action="" method="post">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="">
                   <label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>
                   <select class="form-control" id="status" name="ostatus">
                       <option>Pending Payment</option>
                       <option>driver-assigned</option>
                       <option>processing</option>
                       <option>On Hold</option>
                       <option>completed</option>
                       <option>Cancelled</option>
                       <option>Refunded</option>
                       <option>Failed</option>
                   </select>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block" name="btn-update">Update</button>
               </div>
           </form>
```

my php

```
  <?php
  if (isset($_POST['btn-update'])) {
   $status = $_POST['bookId']; ////order id by post
    $st = $_POST['ostatus']; ///// status selected

     $data = [
          "status " => $st

        ];

     $woocommerce->post('orders/'. $status, $data);
   /////(i tried this to but the same error) $woocommerce->put('orders/' . $status, array('status'=> $st));
         }
```

Comment: Where is `$status` defined? You also have a typo: `oId = ` should be `$oId = `. Copy/paste error? Where exactly are you seeing the error _"status [rest_invalid_param]"_? Is it some JS error in the console, or is it some PHP error? Where is it thrown?

Comment: the error is thrown directly on the php page, where im trying to update, yes $status is defined, its the order id, and $st is the status (completed,,, or any other one i select)

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the api does not allow to change order status other than completed, if status is already completed and I want to set it to processing then I get the error  Invalid parameter(s): status [rest_invalid_param], but if the status is processing and I update it to completed it worked, I do not know if this is a bug or the normal behavior .

so what I did was, create a custom metadata called orderstatus and update the meta data anytime I wanted .

script on WordPress site

```
      <?php
     add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_custom_field_on_placed_order', 10, 2 );
    function add_custom_field_on_placed_order( $order, $data ){

     $order->update_meta_data( '_orderstatus', 'awiting' );
   }
```

//// api php to update order, this goes wherever you are connecting

```
           if (isset($_POST['btn-update'])) {
          $status = $_POST['bookId'];
         $updateorder = ['meta_data'    => [
        ['key'=>'_orderstatus',
      'value' => 'on transit'
         ]

          ]
            ];

          
            $woocommerce->put('orders/' . $status, $updateorder);

            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                 die;


                 }
```